# Is there a way to know which route Flixbus will follow to go from A to B?

Tags: routes, flixbus

So the question is pretty straightforward. Is there a way to know which is the route followed by a Flixbus bus from city A to city B, before buying the ticket?

Comment: I am not sure if this is a duplicate. Which route the bus is driving and where it stops are IMHO two different questions. Perhaps OP can clarify?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I was just wondering if it is possible to have an idea of the general route.

Answer (score 1):

No. If the bus has scheduled stops on the way, these will be approached, but except from that, the bus driver may choose the most practical route depending on traffical circumstances.